# O que é o POSIX?

Tags: api, terminologia, sistema-operacional

Eu sei a sigla Portable Operating System Interface (POSIX), mas o que é? Tem a ver com UNIX? O Windows não pode ser POSIX?

O que isso importa para o desenvolvedor?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

### O que é?

O POSIX como o nome sugere, é um padrão para determinar interfaces comuns entre sistemas operacionais.

O POSIX nada mais é que uma forma de ditar várias características esperadas de um sistema operacional. Normalmente quando escrevemos e compilamos programas em C e C++ é comum tomarmos como verdade alguns comportamentos do sistema.

Por exemplo, quando estamos usando um interpretador de comando que seja compativel com POSIX, se espera que seja possível invocar o comando ls.

### De onde surgiu?

Na década de 70 e 80 começaram a surgir várias iniciativas de sistemas operacionais, e como cada empresa/desenvolvedor fazia suas próprias interfaces percebeu-se que uma padronização era necessária.

Para tentar tornar os programas mais compatíveis entre vários sistemas operacionais, o POSIX foi escrito. Ele basicamente define chamadas de sistema, comandos básicos (como awk e echo), um interpretador de comandos compatível com shell script, vários comportamentos esperados do sistema (como sinais, pipes, gerenciamento básico de processos, etc).

**Nota**: É importante lembrar que Richard Stallman é um dos autores do POSIX.

### O que o UNIX tem a ver com o POSIX?

O UNIX serviu como base para o padrão, pois era mais neutro por assim dizer. Isto não quer dizer que ele seja 100% compatível.

### O Windows é compatível?

De certo modo, podemos dizer que sim. Se você ler atentamente o padrão, irá perceber que o kernel Linux também não atende o padrão 100%. A grande diferença entre o Windows e o Linux é que no Windows temos uma compatibilidade bem menor.

**Nota**: O macOS desde a versão 10.5 Leopard é certificado como compatível com POSIX.

### O que isso importa para o desenvolvedor?

Normalmente quando vamos escrever um programa multiplataforma é necessário estudar quais interfaces estão implementadas e quais não. Normalmente temos bibliotecas que tratam estas diferenças para o programador.

É muito comum hoje evitar o uso de Shell Script quando vamos mirar no Windows, pois ele não tem suporte. Por isso é tão comum vermos scripts de configuração em Python ou ainda um script em shell e outro em bat.

Comment: Excelente explicação, parabéns.